# Meaning of "balls to the wall"

Tags: expressions

According to [this article's](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_phrase_balls_to_the_wall_mean) first two sentences (which I find a bit confusingly formulated), there are two different meanings to the expression.

1. No way out and no options other than a single, not pleasant one.
2. Full speed ahead, all-in, whole-range approach.

After reading/googling, I'm unclear on which of the meanings is the correct one. Furthermore, I realize that it's possible that both are valid, in which case I wonder if there are geographic relation to which is the most commonly used. Is there a trend of popularity (raising/dropping) for any of them?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153114/where-does-the-phrase-balls-to-the-wall-come-from

Comment: @KevinWorkman Please re-read the question I'm asking and compare it to the link you've presented. It's not the same question at all. I'm going to jumpt to a conclusion here and suggest that getting a hit for the search terms doesn't constitute that it's the same question. I can't know for sure how much effort you've put into the comparison but (a) it's hardly difficult to see the difference, once one does more than just take a look in the "*related*" column and (b) it appears to be a common phenomenon which, unintentionally, sabotages the purpose of the site. Nobody wants to see that.   :)

Comment: @Konrad It would be a good idea to explain ***in the question, not in comments*** why this question is not a duplicate of the other. You will need to be absolutely explicit about what is asked here that is not covered there.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Not sure why you seem to be offended, but the question that you asked is indeed answered at the duplicate. I didn't downvote or vote-to-close, so no need to get all bristly. I just remembered seeing it a few weeks ago, did a search for it, and thought I'd provide it for your research. Sorry if that seems out of line to you.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I understand how you figure but I believe you're operating under the false assumption that I **did** post a question that's a duplicate. I didn't. I find it backwards to put responsibility on **me** to motivate why a non-dupe is a non-dupe, just because someone else doesn't put in effort, actually understanding the contents, wrongly assumes that the "related" wall is an oracle etc. Such conduct actually destroys the site. Please note that the **actual** question's been answered, so it **was** understandable what I meant.   :)

Comment: Just because a question is answered before the community closed, it does not mean it was not a duplicate which has an answer elsewhere. Note that I didn't vote to close this question. Had you followed my advice, the question may not have been closed at all.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm not offended and please accept my apology, would you perceive my tone as unkind. I'm just stating that the question asked here **isn't** answered at the post linked by you, at least not in a form that is digestible to my mind. I'll go ahead and assume that you misunderstood what I'm asking about (hint: it's not about what the expression means nor where it comes from). I see it unfit to motivate why my question is non-dupe because that's an implication of "guilt" until proven otherwise. And I fear that such over-nit-pickness damages the site.   :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I saw your comment a few minutes ago so I couldn't react to that. Irregardless, I don't see a point of arguing my case here since I got an answer to the **actual** question I asked. I'm just afraid that such misdirected flagging damages the quality of the contents in the long run. I suggest we pull the plug on this one - I'm sure there are other, real, issues elsewhere needing your attention. (And to be honest, I might be mistaken on this one too. I don't get it since I can clearly see the distinction between my and the linked thread but hey, I might be wrong, might I not?)   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I will note that I didn't "flag" your question as anything, in fact I don't have enough reputation to mark it as a duplicate. I simply posted a link to the question because I remembered seeing it a few weeks ago. Other people with higher reputation must have agreed with me, hence the disclaimer at the top. It doesn't really matter though.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I don't understand which disclaimer you refer to but perhaps it's of no importance at this point. After all - it's all right, Kevin - I do presume that all's been done with best intentions for the site in mind. One can't ask for anything more. In the future, we might behoove of you reading a question more in-depth and comparing the actual contents more carefully. Likewise, perhaps I should consider initiating some of my questions with a disclaimer explaining that it's note a dupe. Have a nice weekend, mate.

Comment: I am talking about the fact that at the top of this question, in big bold letters, it says that it is a duplicate. It has been marked as a duplicate by at least 5 of the most active members of this site (not me), which should tell you something. Instead of continually telling me that I need to read, perhaps you should consider that if everybody but you thinks it's a duplicate, maybe it is. I'll let you have the last word since this bothers you so much though.

Comment: Five voters don't constitute "everybody", Kevin, and frankly I believe that those guys have a lot to do and might be simply affected by your faulty indication. It doesn't really matter in this case, so I'm not making a big fuss of it, but I'd like you to put more effort trying to understand the **actual** question being asked before hitting that "OMG it's a dupe"-button. Otherwise, you're putting the OP in a spot where they need to explain themselves and that's not really fair not healthy for the site. All I'm **very kindly** asking for is that you put more effort before flagging a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balls_to_the_wall) of this phrase is:

> First attested in the 1960s in the context of aviation. Probably coined by pilots whose throttle levers had round, ball-like tops and for whom putting the "balls to the wall" (the firewall of the aircraft) meant making the aircraft fly as quickly as possible.

As we see, the first meaning is direct:

> Full throttle; (at) maximum speed.

The other meaning will be:

> (With) maximum effort or commitment.
>
> 2006, Michael D. Brown, Testimony before the US Senate Homeland Security Committee:
>
> I told the staff...the day before the hurricane struck that I expected them to cut every piece of red tape, do everything they could, that it was **balls to the wall**, that I didn't want to hear anybody say that we couldn't do anything—to do everything they humanly could to respond.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following sources your second definition seems to be more appropriate:

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=balls%20to%20the%20wall&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cballs%20to%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0) the expression seems to be a bit more popular in AmE rather then in BrE.

[Balls to the wall](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/balls-to-the-wall):

extreme; "all out".

> - This is the last game of the season, boys! So, it's balls to the wall!!
> - That guy went balls to the wall to win that race.

[Balls to the wall](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=balls%20to%20the%20wall):

> term used by pilots. when accelerating quickly, the throttle is pushed all the way to the panel and the throttle lever (ball) actually touches the panel (wall). Hence, balls to the wall.

Etymology

> First attested in the 1960s in the context of aviation. Probably coined by pilots whose throttle levers had round, ball-like tops, and for whom putting the "balls to the wall" (the firewall of the aircraft) meant making the aircraft fly as quickly as possible. Probably not, as sometimes suggested, from railroad jargon.

Source: http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/balls_to_the_wall

Other theory of the term's etymology:

> On old steam engines, there was a governor device that had an arm with two steel balls on each end. This spun around, and as the engine went faster the centrifugal force spun the balls higher and higher. When the engine reached its maximum safe power, the balls would be spinning fast and high. When they reached a specific height, a spring would shut down steam and not allow the engine to blow up (over speed itself). **So "balls to the wall" means: as fast as the engine possibly can go.**

Source: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/balls-to-the-wall